# is FSDataInputStream limited to those bytes that were already written when it was created?

Tags: java, hadoop, io, streaming, hdfs

So I'm trying to understand some behavior in HDFS. My goal is to set up a configuration where I open an FSDataOutputStream to some location and then I have some other part of my application open up an FSDataInputStream to that same location immediately, before I write any bytes.

The idea would be that as I write bytes to the FSDataOutputStream, flush them, and call 'sync()', anyone with access to an FSDataInputStream to that same location should be able to read those bytes.

Sadly, it doesn't seem to work that way. When I set up my code that way this happens:

```
FSDataOutputStream writer = fs.create(new Path("/foo/bar"));
FSDataInputStream reader = fs.open(new Path("/foo/bar"));
writer.write(new byte[]{1, 1, 1, 1, 1});
writer.flush();
writer.sync();
System.out.println(reader.available()); // writes '0'
```

However! When I set up my code this way, this happens:

```
FSDataOutputStream writer = fs.create(new Path("/foo/bar"));
writer.write(new byte[] {1, 1, 1, 1, 1});
writer.flush();
writer.sync();
FSDataInputStream reader = fs.open(new Path("/foo/bar"));
System.out.println(reader.available()); // writes '5'
```

Finally, the third test I ran was this:

```
FSDataOutputStream writer = fs.create(new Path("/foo/bar"));
writer.write(new byte[] {1, 1, 1, 1, 1});
writer.flush();
writer.sync();
FSDataInputStream reader = fs.open(new Path("/foo/bar"));
writer.write(new byte[] {2, 2, 2, 2, 2});
writer.flush();
writer.sync();
System.out.println(reader.available()); // writes '5'
```

My takeaway is that FSDataInputStream is always going to be limited in scope to those bytes that were already written when the input stream was created. Is there any way around this? I don't see a 'refresh()' method on the input stream or anything like that.

I would really, really like it if there was some way for me to force an input stream to update its available bytes. What am I missing? What am I doing wrong? Is this simply the wrong way to do stuff like this?

Comment: You should take what you learned and put up your own answer :)

Comment: Once I'm sure I've gotten all the useful feedback I'm gonna get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `DFSInputStream` only refreshes its list of located blocks on open and when it has encounters an error trying to read from a block.  So regardless of what you do in the output stream, the input stream won't be updated.

If you are trying to implement a single-producer/multiple-consumer system, you might look into using something like zookeeper for coordination.

Comment: Argh. I wonder does it make sense to create an alternative input stream implementation that'll expose that refresh method? I guess there's almost certainly a reason they didn't do it that way, I just wish I knew what it was. I'd love to be able to use HDFS as a sort of bus, where anything can see output from anything as it comes in. :-\

Comment: My guess is that they could implement reset, but doing so doesn't really fit the write once/read many times paradigm it was intended for. The overhead that comes along with replication and large block sizes is probably too much for incremental reads/writes.

Comment: Yeah, I'm reading over the DFSInputStream source and I see where you're coming from. Still, an 'invalidateBlock(LocatedBlock block)' method would be really useful. Just force it to get it from the namenode on next read. But, that's also probably a great way to bottleneck your namenode. Hmm.

Comment: Accepting this answer for now. After a lot more digging it looks like even the newly added hflush and hsync methods won't force an DFSInputStream to invalidate its cached blocks. There might be a way to force a bad read, which would invalidate the cache and force it to refresh - I'm going to investigate that if I have time, and will post an update to that effect if it works.